# Ui-grid - How to sort and hide a column on click of respective ui-icons

Tags: angularjs, sorting, hide, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-grid

I need to sort and hide the respective column on click of the respective ui-icons.

ui-icon-close  -> On click of this, respective column should be made hidden.
ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s -> On click of this icon, table should be sorted with respect to the values of that column.

Here is the plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/J6XnIAb7E3MZe62Ixax3?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions1" class="grid"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.gridOptions1 = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name', headerCellTemplate: '<div style="float:left">Name</div><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float:left"></div><div style="float:left" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></div>' }, 
      { field: 'gender', headerCellTemplate: '<div style="float:left">Name</div><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float:left"></div><div style="float:left" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></div>' },
      { field: 'company', headerCellTemplate: '<div style="float:left">Name</div><div class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float:left"></div><div style="float:left" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></div>'}
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use the properties of 'col' and hide the column, the important thing is to refresh grid after every action,

```
 col.hideColumn();
```

similarly you can sort using the gridApi functionality,

```
$scope.grid1Api.grid.sortColumn(col,$scope.uiGridConstants.ASC, false );
```

here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vm0HcEEcKTzyal6s6geB?p=preview)

but you should know that there is already column menu service that can do these for you

here is the link

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/121_grid_menu

Comment: Thanks. I just need to sort and hide the columns. So, I thought that I can remove that column menu and provide these functionalities with the simple ui-icons. Moreover, the column menu involves a click for it to get displayed, which many users here hate it.